# Copy to CIFS share locks machine - any clues from kernel stack trace?

Tags: networking, kernel, cifs

I've got an XPS13 (9343) running Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome shell. I mount two CIFS network shares (which reside on a Debian server) and recently I have been running into problems with the system freezing when copying to those shares.
It doesn't happen every time by any means, and the size of file(s) don't seem to correlate to when it freezes, but it happens every couple of hours and I end up having to do a hard reboot on the XPS - I can access the terminal but 'sudo reboot' just hangs. The error also takes out the local file system, so even a simple ls in a directory on the local ssd without any mounts fails to complete.
Below is the sys log from one of these incidents and I am hoping someone can suggest where I should focus my investigations based on the log:

```
Oct 10 09:57:48 XPS-13 gnome-shell[1941]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.125916] general protection fault: 0000 [#3] SMP PTI
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.125920] Modules linked in: arc4 md4 nls_utf8 cifs ccm fscache rfcomm pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) xfrm_user xfrm4_tunnel tunnel4 l2tp_ppp l2tp_netlink ipcomp l2tp_core xfrm_ipcomp ip6_udp_tunnel vboxdrv(OE) udp_tunnel pppox esp4 ah4 af_key xfrm_algo cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 dell_smbios_smm dcdbas intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf dell_smbios_wmi dell_wmi wmi_bmof sparse_keymap dell_wmi_descriptor ax88179_178a btusb btrtl usbnet btbcm btintel mii bluetooth joydev input_leds uvcvideo wl(POE) videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops ecdh_generic videobuf2_v4l2 snd_usb_audio videobuf2_core snd_usbmidi_lib videodev media snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event dell_laptop dell_smbios snd_rawmidi snd_hda_codec_realtek
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.125955]  snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic serio_raw cfg80211 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec rtsx_pci_ms intel_pch_thermal hid_multitouch mei_me snd_seq snd_hda_core snd_hwdep memstick snd_pcm lpc_ich mei shpchp snd_seq_device snd_timer snd processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf soundcore int3403_thermal dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mac_hid int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_smartconnect acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_plantronics hid_generic usbhid i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc rtsx_pci_sdmmc i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper aesni_intel syscopyarea sysfillrect aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd psmouse sysimgblt
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.125996]  fb_sys_fops drm ahci libahci rtsx_pci wmi i2c_hid hid video
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126004] CPU: 1 PID: 4423 Comm: ShFolders Tainted: P      D    OE    4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126005] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9343/0310JH, BIOS A15 01/23/2018
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126010] RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc+0x81/0x1b0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126012] RSP: 0018:ffffa0c5c31c3618 EFLAGS: 00010286
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126014] RAX: 919a70ed5ff573cf RBX: 919a70ed5ff573cf RCX: 0000000000391fff
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126015] RDX: 0000000000391ffe RSI: 0000000001011200 RDI: 000000000002b550
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126017] RBP: ffffa0c5c31c3648 R08: ffff8e879f4ab550 R09: 0000000000000000
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126019] R10: ffffa0c5c31c3870 R11: ffffffffc03b5000 R12: 0000000001011200
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126021] R13: ffff8e879529bb00 R14: 919a70ed5ff573cf R15: ffff8e879529bb00
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126024] FS:  00007f619aa61700(0000) GS:ffff8e879f480000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126026] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126028] CR2: 0000027487e30010 CR3: 000000020e62c004 CR4: 00000000003626e0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126030] Call Trace:
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126036]  ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126041]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126044]  mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126046]  mempool_alloc+0x71/0x190
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126049]  ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126051]  ? mempool_alloc_slab+0x15/0x20
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126068]  cifs_small_buf_get+0x1a/0x30 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126081]  small_smb2_init+0x62/0xb0 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126092]  SMB2_open+0xc3/0xb50 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126103]  ? cifsConvertToUTF16+0x1e9/0x420 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126106]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126116]  ? cifs_strndup_to_utf16+0xbd/0x110 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126127]  smb2_open_op_close+0xad/0x220 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126137]  ? smb2_open_op_close+0xad/0x220 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126141]  ? alloc_pages_current+0x6a/0xe0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126151]  smb2_query_path_info+0x74/0xf0 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126161]  cifs_get_inode_info+0x4eb/0xab0 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126164]  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xa0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126174]  ? build_path_from_dentry_optional_prefix+0x179/0x3e0 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126184]  cifs_revalidate_dentry_attr+0x1d8/0x250 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126194]  cifs_revalidate_dentry+0x13/0x30 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126203]  cifs_d_revalidate+0x27/0xb0 [cifs]
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126206]  d_revalidate.part.18+0x10/0x20
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126208]  lookup_fast+0x307/0x320
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126210]  walk_component+0x49/0x470
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126213]  link_path_walk+0x1bc/0x5a0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126215]  ? path_init+0x177/0x2f0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126217]  path_lookupat+0x56/0x1f0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126220]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126223]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126225]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126227]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126230]  filename_lookup+0xb6/0x190
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126233]  ? __check_object_size+0xaf/0x1b0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126236]  ? strncpy_from_user+0x4d/0x170
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126239]  user_path_at_empty+0x36/0x40
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126241]  ? user_path_at_empty+0x36/0x40
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126244]  vfs_statx+0x76/0xe0
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126247]  SYSC_newstat+0x3d/0x70
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126250]  SyS_newstat+0xe/0x10
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126253]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126255]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126257] RIP: 0033:0x7f621f0c3775
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126259] RSP: 002b:00007f619aa60838 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000004
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126261] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f6190022810 RCX: 00007f621f0c3775
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126263] RDX: 00007f619aa60860 RSI: 00007f619aa60860 RDI: 00007f6190022810
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126264] RBP: 00007f619aa60920 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000000a
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126265] R10: 00007f6190021621 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f619aa60980
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126267] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 00007f619aa60860 R15: 00007f619aa60b5c
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126269] Code: 87 3c 7b 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 30 0f 84 00 01 00 00 4d 85 f6 0f 84 f7 00 00 00 49 63 5f 20 49 8b 3f 48 8d 4a 01 4c 89 f0 4c 01 f3 <48> 33 1b 49 33 9f 40 01 00 00 65 48 0f c7 0f 0f 94 c0 84 c0 74 
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126300] RIP: kmem_cache_alloc+0x81/0x1b0 RSP: ffffa0c5c31c3618
Oct 10 09:58:12 XPS-13 kernel: [65888.126303] ---[ end trace 627321c99ee3a258 ]--
```

-

Comment: [just try the option vers=3.0 to cifs mounts](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359667)